# How to uncheck the Validate server certificate option on the Authentication tab in the Network Connection on windows 10 via command line?

Tags: windows-10, batch-file, 802.1

To deploy 802.1X configuration among lots of windows 10 workstations I'm looking for a way to uncheck the `Validate server certificate` option on the `Authentication` tab in the `Network Connection on` windows 10 via command line, or other batch approaches.

I could do this by GUI in these steps:

> Right click on the NIC > Properties > Tab authentication > Setting > Uncheck `Validate server certificate`

Does anybody know how to do this in command line or with a script?

Answer (score 2):

I don't know with a script, but if you have an Active Directory environment, you can do it from a group policy. I've accomplished that by using the [GPMC](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa814316(v=vs.85).aspx).

Create a new Group Policy, name it. The configuration to add a network is located in `Computer Configuration / Policies / Windows Settings / Security Settings / Wireless Networks (802.11)`. *-- It isn't specified if wireless or wired, but you can add Wired netwoks as well in the 802.2 section*

There you can configure the network, and in the authentication method properties you can disable the certificate validation.

Remember first to apply on a testing environment, GPOs can mess up with your clients. Be careful.

Hope it helps you accomplish the desired result even though it is not a script.

Comment: I can't find this policy on the local station. Is it only available on an Active Directory server?

Comment: @jayatubi yes, it is

Answer (score 2):

The simplest way, in my opinion, to deploy a WLAN or LAN profile is the following:

1. Create the profile with the GUI on your computer
2. Start a command prompt and use: `netsh wlan show profiles` to show all the available profiles (and hopefully your newly created profile will be listed).
3. Use `netsh wlan export profile <profilename>` to export the profile (an XML file will be created)
4. use `netsh wlan add profile filename=PathToConfig.xml` on other computers to import the profile

Comment: I used the `export` command but I didn't find an `import` command. Never thought that name would be `add`. I should try this.